# Adding a button to the bottom of a listview widget in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I currently have a listview operating on the whole of my screen. I would like to have a button in the bottom of the screen, thus splitting it up so the listview doens't fill up the whole of my window.

This is the current code building the class:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('HT scoreboard'),
  ),
  body: _buildBody(context),
);
}

Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Spillere').orderBy("score", descending: true).snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();

    return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
  },
);
}

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
return ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
  children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
);
}

Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);

return Padding(
  key: ValueKey(record.name),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
    ),
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text(record.name + ": " + record.score.toString()),
      trailing: new IconButton(icon: new Icon(isAdmin ? Icons.add : null, color: Colors.green),
          onPressed: (){
            if(isAdmin){
              record.reference.updateData({'score': record.score + 1});
            }
          }
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

change your buildlist function to include a column with the button and listview as children

```
Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    return Column(
        children:[
            Expanded(
            child: ListView(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                   children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
                   ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
            // fill in required params
            )
         ])
}
```

Comment: It kinda solved my problem too. But this method is causing a new issue: whenever any input field gets focus and keyboard opens, that raise button getting pushed up with keyboard, any solution to prevent that?

Comment: @HarshJatinder did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm actually having the same problem. If someone has any solution for this I'll be really happy to know it. Thanks

Comment: you can use resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false property on the scaffold to avoid the widgets getting pushed up by keyboard

Comment: This also with make it so the widget is always visible at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 22):

To prevent the buttons being pushed above the keyboard;

```
return CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          // list items
        ],
      ),
    ),
    SliverFillRemaining(
      hasScrollBody: false,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton()
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: Wonderful man, Thanks for sharing. I had this problem for a few days.

Comment: This is the only answer that works great, thanks a lot)

Comment: What a beautiful solution! Pretty neat!

Comment: The bottom button still being hidden when you have more than half of screen widgets in SliverToBoxAdapter. Do you know guys how to fix it? Thanks!